# Remove blocking delay() toneMelody function?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, functions

I would like to change the delay() into a nonblocking function in the code below. I've implemented it (a part of a tutorial from arduino.cc) in my code, but the delay() is blocking the rest of my code. Can anyone help me to change this?

```
void speelMelodie(int melodie){

if(melodie == 1){

      for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 8; thisNote++) {

      int noteDuration = 1000 / noteDurations1[thisNote];
      tone(speaker, melody1[thisNote], noteDuration);

      int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
      delay(pauseBetweenNotes); // <-- this one has to be changed

      noTone(speaker);
      }
  }

else if (melodie == 2) {
      // the same part as previous part (for loop)
  }


else if (melodie == 3) {
      // the same part as previous part (for loop)
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at the Arduino example program, BlinkWithoutDelay (File | Examples | Digital | BlinkWithoutDelay). It uses millis() to time the length of the 'on' and 'off' periods of the LED - just what you want to do with the tone.

Comment: Have you looked into examples and tutorials about `millis()`? Did you understand them? What exactly prevents you from changing your code to `millis()`?

Comment: Yes I have, but I don't know how to implement this in my code. I've 5 different melodies like above fragments.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? From your code, it looks like you play a tone and then you pause for some milliseconds (i.e. silence) and then play the next tone. If that is the case, how millis() will help or what delay is blocking?

Comment: @Fahad , I have a lot of other code, I call this function. but due to the delay in this function I can't do with the rest of my inputs outside of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define  global vars befor setup()

```
unsigned long timeStamp = 0; 
bool pauseOn = false;
```

and use it

```
void speelMelodie(int melodie) {

  if (melodie == 1) {

    for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 8; thisNote++) {

      int noteDuration = 1000 / noteDurations1[thisNote];
      if (millis() - timeStamp < noteDuration && pauseOn == false) {
         tone(speaker, melody1[thisNote], noteDuration);
      } else { // reset value and change pauseOn to true
        pauseOn = true;
        timeStamp = millis();
      }
      int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;

      //delay(pauseBetweenNotes); // <-- this one has to be changed
      if (millis() - timeStamp < pauseBetweenNotes && pauseOn == true) {
          noTone(speaker);
      } else {
         pauseOn = false;
         timeStamp = millis();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We need the state variable pauseOn to differentiate between the two states play note or silence. The code compiles, but you have to finetune in your program.
**A final tip** Tutorials **using delay()** other than

- for debuging or
- in setup for initializing hardware

are of very low quality 

-> Its like a blind person talking about color composition.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I get only two notes now.

Comment: Post your code completely by editing your question -its hard to find errors in fragments perhaps unrelated to the real problem

Comment: This is a part of a function that I call elsewhere, so it should be in this part. The whole code is very big.

Comment: Then you have to find it on your own. Now the function is non blocking and as we do not know the rest code it can be caused anywhere (check for other delay() and get rid of them) aso at least give the complete function if you want any further help (and the libs needed - just the include part and the global vars used in the function)

Comment: Allright. I will try it by myself first. Otherwise, when i'm stucking, I'll ask you for help.

Comment: There was still a delay () in it, so that was indeed a mistake. the rest of the function is a repeat of the given part.

I have edited my code above.

Comment: Now I have a constant stop start tone

Comment: You have to apply my changes in the same wy to all three parts first. Then ensure that your loop is not constantly calling the speelMelodie with new params. You can do this with a second bool changeMelodie = true/false; so the loop still goes into the function without everytime changing the params. Copy this part of the caller(loop) with some lines before and after and a rough structure what else is happening in the loop

Comment: Could you give me an example maybe? It isn't still totally clear for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106182/discussion-between-joost-and-codebreaker007).